# Layout options with AndExpand are deprecated from .Net Maui for only StackLayout or all controls?

Tags: xamarin, maui

When I'm using StackLayout with options like FillAndExpand, CenterAndExpand it shows this message
`The StackLayout expansion options are deprecated;please use a Grid instead.`

Because now we HorizontalStackLayout and VerticalStackLayout.

#### The similar post is available on Github here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7346

#### Microsoft documentation also says same:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.layoutoptions.endandexpand?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-layoutoptions-endandexpand

The question is does this applies to all other controls as well in .Net maui like Label, Button, Image, Entry etc; or it is just for StackLayout?

Answer (score 1):

All controls.

- In Xamarin.Forms, *if* parent was *not* a StackLayout, `AndExpand` had no effect anyway. `AndExpand` is not meaningful inside any other layout. Other layouts have their own way of controlling size.

So message says “The *StackLayout* expansion options …" because taking those out from StackLayout, means they are no longer used anywhere.

- Layout is always done by some Layout class. (Layout classes are those with Children: `...Layout`, `Grid`.) Setting a layout option on an element, is telling its PARENT what to do (for the given element).
- Additional info about layouts:
  [Xamarin.Forms MAUI.Controls Layout Differences](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Xamarin.Forms----MAUI.Controls-Layout-Differences).

IMPORTANT (from that link):

> For simplicity of migration from Forms to MAUI, the MAUI.Controls `StackLayout` does honor "AndExpand", at least for the time being.

- That means **Children of StackLayout** can use `..AndExpand`, and have it take effect. For now. BUT this is "deprecated" (may go away), and not recommended (affects performance).
- Instead of `StackLayout`, for performance, use `Vertical/HorizontalStackLayout` or `Grid` or [CollectionView with ItemsLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout).

Comment: Also important is the recommendation at the very bottom of the layout differences wiki page (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Xamarin.Forms----MAUI.Controls-Layout-Differences), explaining exactly how to replace existing AndExpands within a StackLayout with a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This does apply to all controls. The layout options are to arrange and position controls. Microsoft recommends using Grids instead of Stacklayout to arrange and position controls instead of using *AndExpand due to performance issues (already mentioned in your linked posts)